# /var/log/apache2 gets deleted on restart - so apache doesn't start on startup

Tags: apache2

I need help.

Every time I restart apache log directory gets deleted. So after each reboot, I've to mkdir /var/log/apache2

any ideas how to solve this issue?

I've a hunch it's permissions problem, but hey... you know more than me :)

Comment: It looks that [stacer](https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer/issues/467#issue-1051682891) can cause this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you've mounted `/var/log` as `tmpfs`. Check your `/etc/fstab` file for a line like:

```
tmpfs /var/log ...
```

Another possibility is that you're using "disk cleanup" software or have a cronjob that purges the directory on boot.

Comment: Awesome, memory is tricky... I modified fstab to ease write/load on my SDHC boot drive, and I totally forgot about this.

But - I thought ubuntu would write to actuall log files on shutdown.